# Send data through usb port to esp32 with python

Tags: python, arduino, esp32

My main objective is to send pictures through USB port to my ESP32. So first I created an Arduino project, where esp32 can receive data from USB.

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data

boolean newData = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    recvWithEndMarker();
    showNewData();
}

void recvWithEndMarker() {
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char endMarker = '\n';
    char rc;
   
    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (rc != endMarker) {
            receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
            ndx++;
            if (ndx >= numChars) {
                ndx = numChars - 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
            ndx = 0;
            newData = true;
        }
    }
}

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly when I send data with arduino serial monitor. But when I try to send data with my python program, it not really works. Here is the python code:

```
import serial


def sendData(data):
    ser = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600)
    ser.write(data.encode())


def main():
    data = input()
    sendData(data)
    ser = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600)
    while True:
        receiveddata = ser.readline()
        if len(receiveddata) > 0:
            print(receiveddata)
            print("\n")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As everybody sees after I send some text, I start watching the COM4 port. So when I send the text, the python code receives back the sentence "Arduino is ready", so I think the ESP32 restarts after I send the text. Am I right? And how can I fix this? And if I want to send a little bit bigger data, like a picture (it is not as big, only a 128x128 size picture), how can I do it? Thank you for your help.

EDIT:
I try to send data from my computer to ESP32. The device is connected through USB, with a micro usb cable. When I send the data with the python program the ESP32 device not receiving anything. But when I write some text in arduino serial monitor the ESP32 receiving the data immediately. So obviously I do something wrong in my python code.

Comment: Please try to improve your question, by clicking the `edit` button and adding more details. You are trying to send some data **from where** to an ESP32? What is broken? What doesn't work? How? Why?